# How can I test the PHP module in .htaccess

Tags: apache, php, xampp, module

I have installed XAMPP on my Mac for testing and teaching purposes.

One thing I need to do is set up some settings, but I can’t guarantee whether PHP will be running as a module, so I can’t guarantee whether whether I’ll be using the `.htaccess` file or the `.user.ini` file. I know that PHP settings in `.htacess` will cause errors if it’s not running as a module.

One thing I’ve done in the past is wrap the `.htaccess` settings in an `IfModule` directive:

```
<IfModule mod_php…>
    …
</IfModule>
```

I know that the module name may vary according to the PHP version.

I looked inside the `httpd.conf` file to see what version PHP module is running — I’m pretty sure it’s a module in XAMPP, but I can’t be sure about the deployment server. Certainly it doesn’t appear to recognise the `.user.ini` file, and PHP settings in the `.htaccess` files do seem to work.

- The `httpd.conf` file has no reference at all to a loaded PHP module.
- running `phpinfo()` gives me:

> **Loaded Modules** `mod_php`

- According to `phpinfo()`, the PHP version is 8.1.2

However, testing with:

```
SetEnv TEST goodbye
<IfModule mod_php>
    SetEnv TEST hello
</IfModule>
```

or any variation indicates that `mod_php` doesn’t match.

Is there a reliable way in the `.htaccess` file to test this?

**Update:**

Digging through the config files, I find that the module has been loaded in an included file as `php_module`, so using tat value with `IfModule` does indeed work as expected.

However, the question still stands, as we can’t be expected to rifle through the configuration files on the server. Or can we?

Comment: Have you tried setting the environment variable outside of a condition to see if it works?  Then add the condition and see if it is working.

Comment: @Steve I’ve tried that with the `TEST` variable above. I can set it unconditionally to the `goodbye` value, but not conditionally to the `hello` value. I’ve also tried it with two different variable names.

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712825/what-is-mod-php.  It might be worth checking phpinfo() to see if it is being loaded.

Comment: SetEnv is not going to work with http/2 and apache ... on http/1 PHP is loaded for each application and htaccess can set variables but with http/2 PHP is running as a service and no longer has access to these variables ... so you run the risk of broken on update, if this is going into a production website.

Comment: @Wayne the `SetEnv` was only a test to see whether the `IfModule` is working.

Comment: Are you sure you should be using .htaccess? This is useful for multi-tennant hosts otherwise its nothing but problems.